# Initialize a vector of vectors where not all vectors are of same size C++

Tags: c++, string, vector

I have some data like this.

```
static const double v1_arr={2,3,4}
vector<double> v1_vec(v1_arr, v1_arr + sizeof(v1_arr[0]))

static const double v2_arr={9,6}
vector<double> v2_vec(v2_arr, v2_arr + sizeof(v2_arr[0]))

static const double v3_arr={9,6,7,6}
vector<double> v3_vec(v3_arr, v3_arr + sizeof(v3_arr[0]))
```

How do I initialize a vector of vectors `v_v` which contains the three above vectors?

Comment: Do you mean `static const double v1_arr[] = {2,3,4}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a compiler that supports `C++11` you can simply do

```
vector<vector<double>> v_3{v1_vec, v2_vec, v3_vec};
```

If not you will have to do something like

```
vector<vector<double>> v_3;
v_3.push_back(v1_vec);
v_3.push_back(v2_vec);
v_3.push_back(v3_vec);
```

Note that if you can use `C++11` features, you can simply initialize your other vectors like this

```
vector<double> v1_vec{1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
```

and skip the intermediate `v1_arr`.

Comment: On a related note, how will I call the element 2 of v1_vec?
Can I do v3[1][2]?

Comment: @Jim, vectors, like arrays, are zero indexed, so for the second element of the first vector in v3, you want v3[0][1].

Answer (score 3):

You can use a brace enclosed initializer:

```
vector<vector<double>> v_3{v1_vec, v2_vec, v3_vec};
```

Unless you need the "arrays" and `vector objects (assuming you fix the syntax errors to actually declare some arrays) the whole thing can be simplified to

```
vector<vector<double>> v_3{{2, 3, 4}, {9, 6}, {9, 6, 7, 6}};
```